# Redis cache with magento2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I work in the  Magento 2.1.6  right now in optimization process I installed Redis server with this instruction http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html
But  try  cache  clean (php ./bin/magento cache:flush
) in my  store i get this error Redis::pipeline(): Already in pipeline mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is Credis bug: 2 times calling the pipeline method.
Please, patche the file vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php
by the code:

```
// Proxy pipeline mode to the phpredis library
            if($name == 'pipeline' || $name == 'multi') {
                if($this->isMulti) {
                    return $this;
                } else {
                    $this->isMulti = TRUE;
                    $this->redisMulti = call_user_func_array(array($this->redis, $name), $args);
                    //CUSTOM CODE!!!
                    //Credis bug fix: 2 times pipeline() calls below.
                    return $this;
                    //custom code ends
                }
            }
```

in lines 1013-1025

Comment: Please open issue here: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/credis